# .NET build compatibility issue

Tags: .net, msbuild

I have following dev environment setup

1. development: Windows 7 64bit + Visual Studio
2. integration: Windows 2008 64bit
3. test1: Windows 7 64bit + .NET Framework 4.0
4. test2: Windows 7 64bit + .NET Framework 4.5

and following issue with my application:
build on 1. (Visual Stuido) runs fine on test1 und test2 machines
build on 2. (Command line MSBuild) runs fine on test2 but results in Event 1026 Error on test1

Anybody any idea how to fix this issue?

THX

Comment: if  u create a build for `Windows 2008 64bit` and run into win 7 then ofcource it gives u an error..

Comment: I'm creating a build for .NET using MSBuild v4.0 32-bit. The point is, it works with .NET Framework 4.5 but not with 4.0. What could be the difference?

Comment: In general, this will not work. It does work in some cases since 4.5 is an in place replacement for 4.0, but it's not going to work in general. I've, personally, seen problems with types that have moved into different assemblies, and the bindings aren't setup correctly, just like you're seeing

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the reason for this behavior was missing .NET 4.0 SDK on the integration machine. Build was linked against .NET 4.5 Framework and failed to start on .NET 4.0 platform.